# Do C struct members inherit compiler attributes?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, memory-alignment

With most C compilers, one can specify compiler attributes on a struct that define how the members of that struct are aligned in memory. Ex:

```
typedef struct{
    char a;
    char b;
} __attribute__((aligned(2))) TwoChars;
```

If `char a` ends up at the address 0xA (for simplicity), then `char b` will not be at address 0xB, but 0xC, because it's aligned to 2 bytes.

My question is: is this property inherited by struct members? Ex:

```
typedef struct{
    char a;
    char b;
} TwoChars;

typedef struct {
    TwoChars tc;
    char c;
} __attribute__((aligned(1))) ThreeChars;
```

What does this end up looking like in memory? How about with `} __attribute__((aligned(2))) TwoChars`?

Comment: This can be easily tested with your favorite compiler... These attributes are compiler extensions anyway

Comment: I would be surprised if it is "inherited". For a simple reason that two different translation units can be compiled separately, one having the "plain" `TwoChars` variable and one having `ThreeChars`. These are supposed to be compatible. But if it is inheriter in the secont TU, then they will not.

Comment: An yeah, I guess your question more applicable for the `packed` attribute, as pointed out in the answer below.

Comment: I tagged this with GCC since it's a non standard compiler-specific extension. Let me know if that's ok.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** this is a non-standard compiler-specific extension. What I mention in my answer may be applied to GCC and Clang, which I assume is what you mean by "most C compilers".

---

> one can specify compiler attributes on a struct that define how the members of that struct are aligned in memory

No, that's not how `__attribute__((aligned(...)))` works. The `aligned` attribute only applies to the structure itself, not its fields. See the relative [documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

If you want to control the alignment of structure fields, you will have to use the attribute on them.

This:

```c
struct {
    char a;
    char b;
} __attribute__((aligned(8))) foo = { 1, 2 };
```

Will compile to something like:

```
foo:
    .byte   1
    .byte   2
    .zero   6
```

While this:

```c
struct {
    char a __attribute__((aligned(2)));
    char b __attribute__((aligned(2)));
} bar = { 1, 2 };
```

Will do what you want:

```
bar:
    .byte   1
    .zero   1
    .byte   2
    .zero   1
```

Therefore:

> is this property inherited by struct members?

No. Alignment is not something that is inherited by structure members.

---

An interesting thing to know would be if the `packed` attribute is inherited by members of nested structures inside the structure on which it's applied, since `packed` is specifically meant to be inherited by structure members. Documentation does not explicitly state whether this is the case or not, but we can check this easily.

The following code:

```c
struct foo {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct bar {
    struct foo d;
    char e;
    int f;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct bar x = {{101, 102, 103}, 104, 105};
```

Compiles to:

```
x:
    .byte   101
    .zero   3
    .long   102
    .byte   103
    .zero   3
    .byte   104
    .long   105
```

We can see from the above that `packed` only applies to the members of `bar` and is not inherited by the members of `foo`, whereas adding `__attribute__((packed))` to `foo` produces the following:

```
x:
    .byte   101
    .long   102
    .byte   103
    .byte   104
    .long   105
```

In case you were wondering, this also applies to structures defined right inside other structures:

```
struct bar {
    struct {
        char a;
        int b;
        char c;
    } d;
    char e;
    int c;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct bar x = {{101, 102, 103}, 104, 105};
```

Produces:

```
x:
    .byte   101
    .zero   3
    .long   102
    .byte   103
    .zero   3
    .byte   104
    .long   105
```

Whereas adding `__attribute__((packed))` to `d` produces:

```
x:
    .byte   101
    .long   102
    .byte   103
    .byte   104
    .long   105
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. doubt, `packed` does not take any argument.

Comment: Yeah, not literally. I mean this question would be legit if asked about `packed`

Comment: Maybe `aligned` does not apply to members, but applying `packed` to the structure also causes the members to be packed. So the answer is not as simple as saying that members do not inherit from the parent structure. Are there other attributes where the members inherit?

Comment: @EricPostpischil expanded.

Answer (score 0):

That'll work and make ThreeChars aligned at least to 2.

You can test it for yourself:

```
typedef struct{
    char a;
    char b;
} __attribute__((aligned(2))) TwoChars;


typedef struct {
    TwoChars tc;
    char c;
} __attribute__((aligned(1))) ThreeChars;

_Static_assert(_Alignof(ThreeChars) == 2,"");
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9bTzbs

or you can read the documentation of the aligned attribute at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html .

(Unfortunately, the standardized `_Alignas` isn't as convenient to use, as it will be a constraint violation to specify a lower alignment with it.)

Note that only alignment of the whole struct is specified here, so while     `TwoChars tc;` will be two-aligned and therefore affect the alignment of `ThreeChars`, the subsequent members will not have a higher than natural alignment.

The latter fact can be verified by `_Static_assert`ing that the offset of be is 1 (`_Static_assert(offsetof(TwoChars,b)==1,"");`), as natural alignment would suggest, and so it cannot be 2-aligned.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Well, thanks but I believe only the initial yes was misguided and completely wrong (deleted now). The rest, I believe, checks.

Comment: Yep, removed my comment when I saw your edit. Though this is not very clear if you ask me. Seems like your first line is answering a different question than what OP asks.